# get the data of a specific row in the order it displays

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to get the data of a row from the table.
this is how I currently do it

```
const focusedCell = params.api.getFocusedCell();
                if (focusedCell)
                {
                    const row =  params.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(focusedCell.rowIndex);
                }
```

the resone I get it from the focused cell and than get the the row by index (rather than get the selected row) is that when I righ click on a cell, it dosen't select the entire row.
the 'row' object contains the data but for some reason it's not in the order it's displayed on the actual table.
any ideas why, or how to get it in the right order?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the right order? Your data property is an object which doesn't have a specific ordering. The displayed order of the columns is defined by the order of the column definitions which is completely separate from the properties on the row data objects.

Comment: right click on a cell means interacting with context menu. if you are using enterprise version you can easily use a callback on right-click to retrieve the node information which will give you the index number as well.